# Using R, how can I disaggregate data separated by commas into separate rows?

Tags: r

I have a data frame where certain observations are separated by commas and I would like to separate them into different rows. I know there is a way to do this using the separate_rows function from tidyr, but I have an additional constraint.

Here is code to get my data frame:

```
dat <- structure(list(cit.num = c("29496, 37063", "29496, 37063", "36706, 36707", 
"36706, 36707"), civ.race = c("Black", "White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic"
), civ.sex = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"), count = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Here is what the data look like:

```
  cit.num      civ.race civ.sex count
1 29496, 37063 Black    Male        2
2 29496, 37063 White    Female      2
3 36706, 36707 Hispanic Female      2
4 36706, 36707 Hispanic Male        2
```

cit.num identifies an individual citizen. I know that 29496 refers to the black male, and 37063 refers to the white female. Is there a way to separate the rows such that the first value is matched with the correct civ.race and civ.sex? Here is my desired output:

```
  cit.num civ.race civ.sex count
1 29496   Black    Male        2
2 37063   White    Female      2
3 36706   Hispanic Female      2
4 36707   Hispanic Male        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the cit.num that should correspond to each combination of civ.race and civ.sex, I think it would be easier to do a join with the corresponding keys. Here is the code to do that using `left_join`.

```
library(tidyverse)

keys <- data.frame(civ.race = c("Black","Black","White","White","Hispanic","Hispanic"),
                   civ.sex = c("Male","Female","Male","Female","Male","Female"),
                   cit.num = c(29496,29495,37064,37063,36707,36706),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

dat %>%
  #Drop you original cit.num column
  select(-cit.num) %>%
  #Do the join using civ.race and civ sex to match the entries in dat and keys
  left_join(keys, 
            by = c("civ.race","civ.sex"))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# civ.race civ.sex count cit.num
# <chr>    <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
# 1 Black    Male        2   29496
# 2 White    Female      2   37063
# 3 Hispanic Female      2   36706
# 4 Hispanic Male        2   36707
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop:

Key to it is that you define a sequence of uneven numbers:

```
seq(1, nrow(dat), by = 2)
```

That sequence you instruct `for` to loop over:

```
for(i in seq(1, nrow(dat), by = 2)){
  dat$cit.num[i] <- gsub(", \\d+", "", dat$cit.num[i])
  dat$cit.num[i+1] <- gsub("\\d+, ", "", dat$cit.num[i+1])
}
```

Output:

```
dat
  cit.num civ.race civ.sex count
1   29496    Black    Male     2
2   37063    White  Female     2
3   36706 Hispanic  Female     2
4   36707 Hispanic    Male     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` alternative. You can separate your `cit.num` column into 2 columns, `first` and `second`.

Then, grouping by this combination, you set `cit.num` to be either the `first` or `second` number (`first` if the first of the two rows, and `second` otherwise).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  separate(cit.num, into = c("first", "second")) %>%
  group_by(first, second) %>%
  mutate(cit.num = ifelse(row_number() == 1, first, second)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(c(-first, -second))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  civ.race civ.sex count cit.num
  <chr>    <chr>   <int> <chr>  
1 Black    Male        2 29496  
2 White    Female      2 37063  
3 Hispanic Female      2 36706  
4 Hispanic Male        2 36707
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have only two numbers in `cit.num` we could use `separate_rows` to get data in different rows and select 1st and 4th row in each `cit.num`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(temp = cit.num) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(cit.num) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  slice(c(1, 4)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-temp)


# cit.num civ.race civ.sex count
#  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <int>
#1 29496   Black    Male        2
#2 37063   White    Female      2
#3 36706   Hispanic Female      2
#4 36707   Hispanic Male        2
```